# 4 isolated stops on a 12-station route

Tags: combinatorics

> A train on a 12-station route has to be stopped at 4 stations with no two stops consecutive. How many ways can the stops be arranged?

Let $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$ be the stops.
$$A\to x_1\to S_1\to x_2\to S_2\to x_3\to S_3\to x_4\to S_4\to x_5\to B$$
$x_1$ is the number of stations between $A$ and $S_{1}$, and similarly for the other $x_i$'s.

I want to go further, could some help me with this?

Comment: Before I post my answer, do you know of stars and bars? Go check that.

Comment: yes Parcly i know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard multiset (stars-and-bars) problem. Consider the eight stations where the train *doesn't* stop, which define nine gaps:

```
_S_S_S_S_S_S_S_S_
```

We want to add four more stations where the train *does* stop into these gaps, with at most one stop per gap to satisfy the condition of no consecutive stops. There are $\binom94=126$ ways of doing this, and this is therefore the answer.